# How do I re-use (include) Junit test block in other tests

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I am fairly new to the JAVA world - coming from a ColdFusion background - and have been learning Java because I'm learning Selenium WebDriver /JUnit. I have written several test classes that test admin functionality that follow a similar structure.

```
public class myclass{

public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public static void startDriver(){
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("some url");
}

@Test
public void myLogin(){

    some login code

}

@Test
public void somefunction() {

    other admin function to test

}
```

My question is this - since all my tests require the user to log in - I end up having to re-use the "mylogin" test code over and over. How can I write the tests to simply "include" (like the "cfinclude" tag in ColdFusion) the login code so that if changes are made to the login page functionality - I only have to change it in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the myLogin() functionality in a base parent class what you will need to extend in all of your test classes to access this functionality across various tests:

```
public abstract class MyBaseTest {
    public void myLogin() {
        <some login code>
    }
}

public class MyClass extends MyBaseTest {
    @Test
    public void somefunction() {
        super.myLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect - TYVM - I forgot about the concept of a "superclass"

Answer (score 3):

Java hasn't got a lexical include statement like ColdFusion or C. This is by design, because just pasting sourcecode before compilation is a very unclean way of sharing code between modules.

But there are many other ways to approach this issue. Here are two:

1. Create your own library with commonly used functionality encapsulated in methods and use this library in your tests
2. Add [`setUp` and `tearDown` methods](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+extreme+programming/Chapter+4.+JUnit/4.6+Set+Up+and+Tear+Down/) for your test classes. These methods are executed before and after each one of your test methods. Note that test classes can inherit from each other. So when you have lots of test classes with identical `setUp` and `tearDown` methods, you can make them extend a common base class and implement these methods in the base class once.

Comment: If you are using a fairly current version of JUnit, you can also look into Rules to provide similar support.

Comment: You can annotate myLogin() with `@Before` to make execute before every `@Test` method (ie treat it as a Set Up method)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) annotation to accomplish this. The annotated method will run before every @Test annotated method. Similarly you could use [@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) to logout after every unit test, if needed.